# Deserialize JSON with Class containing Generic Object

Tags: java, android, generics, gson, android-json

I am using GSON to deserialize a JSON string.

```
mGSON.fromJson(json, mClass)  //mClass == ClassA.class
```

The problem comes in when using the class below

```
public class BaseModel<T> {
    String StatusCode, Description;
    T Data;
}
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
mGSON.fromJson(json, mClass<DataClass>);
```

or

```
mGSON.fromJson(json, (BaseModel<DataClass>).class);
```

but obviously this doesn't work.

Comment: [The documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types) seems to cover this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and:

```
mGSON.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<BaseModel<DataClasss>>() {});
```

See [here](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) for more information.

Comment: Here is what I ended up using: Type tt = new TypeToken<BaseModel<DataClass>>() {}.getType();  Thank you!